# Howto merge two avi files using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, join, merge, ffmpeg, cat

I'm unable to merge two avi videos together. 
google is full of below examples:

```
cat file1.avi file2.avi file3.avi > video_draft.avi
after appending the data together using cat above, you need to re-index the draft movie like this:

mencoder video_draft.avi -o video_final.avi -forceidx -ovc copy -oac copy
Now you're video_final.avi file will be right to go.
```

but it doesn't work for me, the first video is converted and that's it.

Comment: [FFmpeg wiki: How to concatenate (join, merge) media files](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You should look into the [concat demux and concat protocol](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files) that was added in ffmpeg 1.1. Assuming the codecs are the same you create a file (example `mylist.txt`):

```
file '/path/here/file1.avi'
file '/path/here/file2.avi'
file '/path/here/file3.avi'
```

Then pass that file to ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy video_draft.avi
```

You can use this command to make the list:

```
ls *.avi | while read each; do echo "file '$each'" >> mylist.txt; done
```

The linked page has more advanced examples for dealing with issue like different codecs/formats.

Comment: can you please say me how to setup ffmpeg in my android project

Comment: This procedure gives to me the following error:`Unknown input or output format: concat`

Comment: update ffmpeg to recent version to avoid `Unknown input or output format: concat`

Comment: And if you use `avconv` b/c `ffmpeg` is not provided by your Linux distro, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19314483) on how to avoid the `Unknown input or output format: concat` error.

Answer (score 25):

You can use this single command line:

```py
ffmpeg -i "concat:input1.avi|input2.avi|input3.avi" -c copy output.avi
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to add -safe 0 for recent versions of ffmpeg, and it needs to be before the file list.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt ...
```

Comment: 1) `-safe 0` is only needed in certain situations. See the [concat demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1) for details. 2) You have a typo in your example: change `-I` to `-i`.